# I lost some files

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside with Windows 8 and my hardisk got a three partitions one for windows another one for ubuntu and the last is NTFS partiotion .. 
I copied data to the NTFS partition from my ubuntu after a while I logged in Windows 8 and copied another file to the same partition .. I came back to linux but I found that all the previous data I copied to the NTFS partiotion didn't exist

I tried unhide the files but didn't pay off ,, I also tried to list the files from the terminal inorder to find them but I didn't find them althought the disk appears FULL and didn't have a space

What I have to do to regain my files and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was almost certainly caused by a Windows feature called Fast Startup, Hybrid Boot, or Hybrid Shutdown. This feature turns an ordinary shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk operation. This speeds up the subsequent reboot, but it's *incompatible* with dual-boot configurations. The trouble is that filesystems are left in an inconsistent state, so if another OS (such as Ubuntu) tries to access them, the best-case scenario is that the other OS won't permit it and the worst-case scenario is that you'll end up with filesystem damage. To fix this problem, you must disable the Fast Startup feature, as described [here,](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) among other places.

Since you say you *copied* the files, you've presumably got the originals elsewhere. If so, I recommend you simply disable Fast Startup and move on. If you've lost the files, you'll need to use a low-level NTFS data recovery tool to find them. [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) might do this, but chances are there's a Windows-specific tool that will do it better. I'd ask on a Windows forum if you need advice in this arena.

Answer (score -1):

There are many data recovery soft. They will scan your disk any try to find deleted files. 
Look at this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Recovery

To avoid losting data in future, you may need to turn off **hybrid boot** in windows, and make sure windows partition is unmounted before rebooting linux.